# in python how can i write code to let the user enter the values of nested dictionary with list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
{
    '1': {'s': ['2', '4'], 'c': ['3']},
    '2': { 's': ['5'] },
    '3': { 's': ['5'],'c': ['1']},
    '4': {'s': ['1'],'c': ['5'] },
    '5': {'s': ['2'], 'c': ['3']}


}
```

if i want the user input these values what is the correct code to do that and the user can enter different values every time  run the code even the length of list inside the dictionary is changeable

i try this code but i don't know how let the user enter the values of dictionary with list because this code not get the values from user

```
myDict = dict()
list = ['1','2','3']
for n in list:
    for j in range(int(n), int(n) + 2):
        myDict.setdefault(j, []).append(n)

print(myDict)
```

Comment: do you want the user to enter the dictionary keys, or just the values?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the user to enter in order to produce that dictionary?  How do they specify which are the `s` values and which are the `c` values, and which numbers they go with?

Comment: A dictionary whose keys are just ordered integers is a code smell. Are you sure you don't need just a list?

Comment: i have nfa machine and s and c means the alphabet of machine, and s for example if i in state 1 and read s machine can transmit from state 1 to state 2 or 4

Answer (score 1):

Have the user input the dictionary as JSON, and then you can just read it with `json.loads()`:

```
import json
import pprint

myDict = json.loads(input("Enter data (JSON): "))
pprint.pprint(myDict)
```

```
Enter data (JSON): {"1": {"s": ["2", "4"], "c": ["3"]}, "2": { "s": ["5"] }, "3": { "s": ["5"],"c": ["1"]}, "4": {"s": ["1"],"c": ["5"] }, "5": {"s": ["2"], "c": ["3"]}}
{'1': {'c': ['3'], 's': ['2', '4']},
 '2': {'s': ['5']},
 '3': {'c': ['1'], 's': ['5']},
 '4': {'c': ['5'], 's': ['1']},
 '5': {'c': ['3'], 's': ['2']}}
```

Comment: You could also use `ast.literal_eval` if you want to use Python syntax rather than JSON. JSON is probably more familiar, though.

Comment: I think the OP wanted the data to be input interactively, not as a whole bunch of text. Otherwise, why not just read it from a json file or so?

Comment: That's what I would have thought, but OP didn't respond to requests for clarification on that point, which means they aren't opinionated -- so why complicate it?  Using a standard input format is usually better than rolling your own unless you have very specific requirements that demand it.  With this much data, entering it one element at a time in an interactive prompt would get annoying very quickly if you wanted to make minor changes to the state machine between sessions.

Comment: i wrote program in python to construct NFA  machine  to accept or reject the string and let the user to enter the states, alphabets,  start state and final state and i use dictionary to store the values of transition function and i want user to enter the transition list then the output will be accept or reject.

Comment: That doesn't at all clarify *how* you want them to enter the transition list.  :)  *What actual buttons do you want them to push on their keyboard to produce the dict in your example?*

Answer (score 0):

If you need the data ingestion to be interactive, where the user input each value at a time, you can try this:

```
def fun(alhabet, states):
  result = dict()
  for s in states:
    result[s] = dict()
    for a in alhabet:
      trs = input(f"Upon reading {a}, state {s} can be transmited to: ").split()
      if trs: result[s][a] = trs
  return result

print(fun(['s', 'c'], range(1, 6)))
```

For the input:

```
> Upon reading s, state 1 can be transmited to: 2 4
> Upon reading c, state 1 can be transmited to: 3
> Upon reading s, state 2 can be transmited to: 5
> Upon reading c, state 2 can be transmited to: 
> Upon reading s, state 3 can be transmited to: 5
> Upon reading c, state 3 can be transmited to: 1
> Upon reading s, state 4 can be transmited to: 1
> Upon reading c, state 4 can be transmited to: 5
> Upon reading s, state 5 can be transmited to: 2
> Upon reading c, state 5 can be transmited to: 3
```

The output is:

```
{1: {'s': ['2', '4'], 'c': ['3']},
 2: {'s': ['5']},
 3: {'s': ['5'], 'c': ['1']},
 4: {'s': ['1'], 'c': ['5']},
 5: {'s': ['2'], 'c': ['3']}}
```

Comment: the code doesn't work. it gave me this error   print(fun(['s', 'c'], range(1, 6)))
TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'states'

Comment: It was a typo in the function declaration. I fixed it now